# ¿Como hago para adicionar 1 en una campo de una tabla, cuando se da un clic a un enlace?

Tags: html, ajax

El 1 a que hago referencia es simplemente sumar 1 a un campo de una tabla, haciendo clic en un enlace.
Este es el codigo del enlace:

```
<?php if ($pagina) { ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <h3><a href="<?php echo $pagina['url']?>" target="blank"><span 
      class="hint--top-right" data-hint="Clic aquí para acceder a la web de 
      la propiedad">PAGINA WEB</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Y esta es la funcion que debería ejecutar:

```
# ----- Sumar click_website a la propiedad
function addClickWebsite($conexion, $id)  {
  $consulta = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE alquileres set 
      click_website=click_website+1 where id=$id");
  $consulta->execute();
  return $consulta->fetchAll();
}
```

Necesito ayuda para enlazar la funcion al clic en el enlace, alguien me dijo que debo hacerlo con ajax, pero lamentablemente no tengo conocimiento. Gracias.

Comment: Que lenguaje estas usando en el servidor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), podés captar el evento `click` y hacer que se ejecute del lado del servidor dicha acción.

#### HTML

```
<?php if ($pagina) { ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <h3><a href="<?php echo $pagina['url']?>" target="blank" id="clickEvent"><span 
      class="hint--top-right" data-hint="Clic aquí para acceder a la web de 
      la propiedad">PAGINA WEB</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

#### Javascript:

```
// le agrego al id clickEvent un evento de click para luego
// ejecutar el ajax
$('#clickEvent').click(function() {
  var id_alquiler = 232; // acá reemplazo esto por el id del alquiler que corresponda
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'mi-accion.php',
    data: {id: id_alquiler},
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('acción realizada', data);
    }
  });
});
```

#### mi-accion.php

```
# ----- Sumar click_website a la propiedad

// acá hago la conexión a la DB
$conexion = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "password");

// id que paso por javascript
$id = $_POST['id'];

$consulta = $conexion->prepare(
  "UPDATE alquileres set click_website=click_website+1 where id=$id"
);
$consulta->execute();
echo json_encode($consulta->fetchAll());
```

Comment: Gracias Kleith, pero me puedes aclarar lo siguiente ya que no se como es la sintaxis de Js ni Ajax, en la linea 
url: 'mi-accion.php',

como paso los parametros de coneccion y busqueda? quedaría entonces:

url: 'addClickWebsite($conexion, $id)', 

o de que forma le paso los parametros a la funcion?

Comment: Cierto, te explico. Si tenés que pasar algún parámetro desde el cliente al servidor, o sea de javascript a php, lo tenés que pasar dentro de un atributo llamado `data` y ahí va otro objeto con los valores, p. ejemplo: `$.ajax({ ... data: {id: 2382} ... })` y luego en el PHP lo vas a obtener como variable `$_GET` o `$_POST`.

Comment: Me parece que tengo que hacer los 2 pases, de php a Js y de Js a php, como hago para pasar en ambos casos estas dos variables:
$conexion y $id de php a Js y luego de Js a php nuevamente las mismas variables, para que se pueda ejecutar la funcion addClickWebsite, te repito que no se la sintaxis, por eso estoy tan confundido. Gracias!

Comment: Por lo que veo, sólo tenés que pasar el `id` desde el data de ajax y luego en el PHP, generar la nueva `$conexion` para luego utilizarla y si necesitás devolver algo, simplemente hacés un `echo json_encode($consulta-fetchall());`, luego en el  `success: function(data)` de javascript podés manejar esa información.

Comment: Chequea la respuesta, ahí di algo más detallado.

Comment: Ok, ya funciona, habia un par de detalles, como que la variable hay que encerrarla entre comillas y la ultima linea de Ajax no lleva ",". Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con Javascript es sencillo, puedes añadir cualquier campo: te dejo la documentación para que lo implementes, es sencillo.

Fuente de consulta: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement